# Laravel pagination not work.

Tags: mysql, laravel, pagination

How i can create pagination from this query?

```
$cars = DB::select('SELECT c.id, c.model, c.color, c.code FROM cars c, details d WHERE d.car_id=c.id AND d.point_type = ? ORDER BY d.date DESC', array(Auth::user()->id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cars = DB::select('SELECT c.id, c.model, c.color, c.code FROM cars c, details d WHERE d.car_id=c.id AND d.point_type = ? ORDER BY d.date DESC', array(Auth::user()->id))->paginate(15);
```

Then in your views...

```
{{ $cars->links(); }}
```

Check the pagination section for more detail http://laravel.com/docs/pagination